# Prestashop generating product image paths

Tags: prestashop

I do not know how to go about it. The situation looks like this:

On the server in the folder / img / p / I have uploaded photos of 3 thousand. products, each photo is described by the product code - index eg:

Product A has the index 112233

On the server I have such a file 112233.jpg

How can I make Prestashop read images from the server according to a parameter such as the index?

It may happen that several photos are assigned to a given product, then the diagram looks like this: 112233-2.jpg, 112233-3.jpg.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The preferred way would be to import your images to Prestashop (make a CSV file: a list of images in one column, and add the same index in the second column; use Prestashop default function import). In this case you can see and use images in Pretashop way.
Another way is to modify `controllers/front/ProductController.php` (add the function you are changing to `override`), but this is not good ;)